# VB.net 2013 Asking a for Input in a For Loop

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to create a very simple program where I ask a user to guess a number. They have 10 guesses which I use a For loop to track and limit their guesses. However, I can only get it to ask for input once and then it runs the loop ten times saying "Sorry try again" and then the program ends. Is there a way that I can ask the question each time the loop repeats?

```
For x = 1 To 10 
    If num1 = 5 Then 
        txtOut.AppendText("You win") 
    Else 
        txtOut.AppendText("Try Again") 
    End If 
Next
```

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: When you have a problem with a piece of your code, you could write a long question here describing the problem, but just putting the code that doesn't work is a better explanation than thousand words [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: My apologies. the section of code that I am having trouble with is here.       'code'For x = 1 To 10
            If num1 = 5 Then
                txtOut.AppendText("You win")
            Else
                txtOut.AppendText("Try Again")
            End If
        Next

Comment: Hint: your code (which you forgot to show to us) would be tidier with a `While` loop and a counter variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        For x As Integer = 0 To 10
            Dim input As Integer = CInt(InputBox("Enter a Number", "Input"))
            If input = intAnswer Then
                txtOut.AppendText("You win")
                Exit For
             Else
                txtOut.AppendText("Try Again")
            End If
        Next
```

This should be along the lines of what you need to do, you aren't prompting the user to enter text in the For Loop in your comment. It's important to prompt them every time, because this will be what stops the program from iterating all the way through the loop instantly.

Edit: This will get you along the way, as it fixes the issue but don't forget to handle situations where the input wont be an integer!

Comment: Did you mean to write `Exit For` after `txtOut.AppendText("You win")`?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I forgot to put the Exit For in, edited it in now.

Answer (score -2):

We need to see your code to be able to point out where it's going wrong. It sounds like you're calling for input outside the For loop, whereas to ask for it each time you need to put it inside.

pseudo-code:

```
i = 0
answer = randomNumberGenerator
For (i<10)
ask for input
if input = answer then
output "Congrats! You guessed right!"
break
else
output = "Sorry, try again!"
i++
end if
end loop
```

Comment: Can't you show an example in VB.NET instead of pseudo code?